# Azure ACS + MVC + WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure, acs

I got a MVC web application that authorizes users through Azure ACS. Now I want my web application to make calls to my WCF services. Since these services can be called by other applications I want them to be secured through ACS also. I'm at a loss on how to set this up. Can I reuse the security tokens in my WCF service calls somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formally you can't because these are 2 different (autonomous) "apps". Tokens are issued for a specific app (or "Relying Party"). Your website should request a second token for the web service. You have 2 options:

1- Simply get a token under a service identity (that is the identity the web site is assuming) and attach it to your calls to the web service. WCF bindings support this out of the box (albeit complex, as any WCF configuration),.

2- Get a token for WCF "on behalf" of the original user. This is a delegation scenario, in which the identity of the original caller to the web app is transferred to the service.

The first option is rather simple (putting aside the WCF specifics). The second option is more complex one and not supported in ACS (as far as I know), because it requires a special endpoint that understands and issues **ActAs** tokens.

You *could* use the same token for both the web site and the service if you own both and are "the same app". This is a pragmatic shortcut and not a pure implementation, and might have other implications (e.g. the same app in ACS, the WCF can't easily distinguish that it is being called from your website or external parties, etc).

In that case, the MVC app must keep the token that was sent to it. There's a setting for that (bootstraptoken=true). The WIF API in .NET 4.5 changed a little bit, so there might be something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've started to reconsidered my architecture and instead of having the MVC app calling a WCF service, I'll have it communicate to the database directly - I get rid of overhead and issues like this one.. any third party app will have to go through the MVC web api.. not a big deal I think.